# Ultra High sensitive sound capturing sensors

Tags: sensor, sound, microphone

We are working on a project which involves in capturing signals traveling through a rail line. Unfortunately in our country, we have lots of joint in between rail tracks. So the signal gets attenuated and becomes very hard to capture using normal devices like microphones and accelerometers. Could anyone please tell us of good (actually very good) sound capturing devices?

Answer (score 6):

If the sound isn't there you can't capture it.  Any microphone can be made as sensitive as you want with amplification.  What you are really asking for is good signal to noise ratio, not sensitivity.

Look for small microphones that can be attached directly to the track and otherwise have a low inherent noise floor.  For good signal to noise ratio, the analog amplifying circuit becomes important too.  You want to carefully filter any power supply going near this circuit, shield it from capacitively picking up other signals, filter out RF to keep the frequencies to the range the electronics can handle as intended, use guard traces, etc.  Be extra extra careful in the first amplification stage, which will probably have a voltage gain of around 30.  After that, the signal will be higher level and lower impedance, and much less susceptible to noise.

As for the best microphone, I'm not up on which technologies inherently provide the best signal to noise ratio.  Look thru some datasheets and possibly build a few with circuits to measure the noise floor.

Look carefully at the frequency spectrum of your expected signal.  There might be opportunity to filter out large ranges of what the microphone can pick up, thereby eliminating up front noise with that out of band frequency content.

Comment: The stuff we use for undersea acoustics is piezoelectric ceramic. There are a lot of manufacturers. They are tricky to work with, however; they typically have a source impedance in the 100k range, so to get a low-noise preamp working you'll need a low-voltage-noise (e_n) **and** low-current-noise (i_n) amplifier. The current noise will create a voltage noise across the source (multiply i_n by Z_s to get e_in) which can exceed e_n by a large amount on many "low noise" amplifiers. If you can't get a low i_n, you have to put a JFET buffer stage in front of the amp.

Answer (score 0):

Analog Devices makes a MEMS sensor with a signal to noise ratio of 61-dB A-weighted. MEMS are of course integrated devices with the mic and associated amplification all on one chip, no need to design your own amp, just plug and play. The part number for this device is ADMP 401 although there may be newer versions of this sensor.

Comment: Fred, can you please make it a habit in questions and answers to provide a link if you mention uncommon components? TIA

Comment: OK Steve, I'm getting lazy in my old age